Vee-validate v4 how to force lazy validation
Maybe a dumb question but does any body know how to force a field to be lazy validated using vee-validate v4?
I am finding that my validation rules being executed on each keystroke instead of waiting till the field is tabbed away.
The vee-validate v4 doc doesn’t make it easy to find this information and there is a small sample which talks about lazy validation but I am finding it to not be true.
It still executes the rule each time but suppresses issuing the error message until the field is tabbed. That is not lazy validation.
The function that my rule calls is an expensive Rest api call and I cannot have it called on each key stroke , fail but simply hide the error message.
Any help or advice on what would seem to be a very simple problem would be really appreciated.
I am finding the vee-validate v4 is almost a complete rewrite of the applications from the previous v3 due to what seems a lot of breaking changes that were introduced.

I have received a reply from the author of vee-validate…
Quote:
This was reported a lot of times and is intended.
Validation being lazy means the errors are generated lazily, but the validation still occurs.
This means there is no solution for it, but there might be workarounds you can employ:
So I am left with having to try to create a hack for this.
I do think that the use of the term “lazy” validation is very misleading as it does not suppress any validation whatsoever.

Wait, so a heavy computation is still performed all the time even if it's "lazy"? Damn. I thought it would just be marked as "dirty". I understand your concerns haha. Maybe give it a try to Formkit? Might solve your issue in a better way?

To call it “lazy” validation is false. I spent a few days trying to debug my code to understand why validation was taking place on every keystroke and couldn’t understand why any error message was only being displayed intermittently.  Suppressing the error message but allowing heavy validation to still take place is very misleading in my opinion.
